# How to @forward some rules using both a `with` and a `show` clause?

Tags: sass, dart-sass

The SCSS `@forward` rule supports a couple nice features:

1. `@forward './colors' show $red, $green, $blue;` will only forward `$red`, `$green`, and `$blue` from `./colors`. All other values that `./colors` would otherwise export are ignored.
2. `@forward 'library' with ($space: 2em);` will make `$space` available to the library, overriding any default that library may have for `$space`.

How can I use these both together? In my case I'm using the `include-media` library. I want to define a module that wraps it like this (slightly simplified):

```
@forward 'include-media with (
  $breakpoints: ( 'small': 400, 'medium': 700, 'large': 1000 )
) show media, media-context;
```

The goal here is to both provide the library the `$breakpoints` value it's expecting, and forward only the `media` and `media-context` mixins. Unfortunately that code fails to compile with this error:

```
Error: expected ";".
  ╷
3 │ ) show media, media-context;
  │   ^
```

I get similar results if I put the `show` clause before the `with` clause.

It seems sub-optimal, but I could imagine this working with two files:

```
// file _withBreakpoints.scss
@forward 'include-media' with (
  $breakpoints: ( 'small': 400, 'medium': 700, 'large': 1000 )
);
```

```
// file _filtered.scss
@forward './withBreakpoints' show media, media-context;
```

Surely there's a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked that and cannot confirm the issue. (Tested with Compiler: VS Code extension Live SASS by(!) Glenn Marks).

**But important:** `hide/show` must be called BEFORE `with`.

Following syntax works here (just examples):

```
//### forward with hide

@forward 'variables' hide $color_red with(
    $color_orange: yellow,
    $color_gray: magenta,
); 



//### forward with show

@forward 'variables' show $color_red with(
    $color_red: orange,
);
```

---

But there seems to be some other issues in your code:

- You try to `@forward` a module only showing `media, media-context` (that are the only members which are forwarded) but you try to change variable `$breakpoints` which is not shown/forwarded because it is not in the list.
- Just as polite guessing (not knowing): You want to show/forward `media, media-context`. Are that functions/mixins? If var you should write them with `$`.
- You missed the closing quote after the forwarded file: `@forward 'include-media  ...`

So, maybe you like to try something like this:

```
@forward 'include-media' 
show [$?]media, [$?]media-context, $breakpoints
with (
  $breakpoints: ( 'small': 400, 'medium': 700, 'large': 1000 ),
);

//### Think about 'show': 
//### What is not in the list is not fowarded and cannot be used.
//### So I am not sure ...
//### if your module needs more members to be forwarded so it works. 
//### Depends on your module.
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, I was misled by an outdated VSCode linter. The `@forward` statement works with the `show` clause before the `with` clause. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't try to forward `$breakpoints` because I considered it configuration for the library, and not a value I wanted to export myself. In my initial testing, forwarding `$breakpoints` does not seem necessary. Is there something I'm missing?

Also, `media` and `media-context` are mixins, so the absence of the `$`s is intentional.

Comment: @Jwashton Were you able to get the result you expected without additionally showing the $breakpoints variable? I understand your use case in only wanting to expose the mixins